# Embedding Shiny app in knitr document

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app which has a ui.R, server.R and global.R. The app directory (name = dash) contains the folder 'data' in which the dataset resides. Also, this app folder is inside the project's working directory.
In global.R I read the data as:

```
dash <- read.table("data/ntraj1acc.txt", sep=",", header=T)
```

This app works fine. Now, I am trying to embed it in a ioslides presentation which otherwise works good. The example in [External Applications](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_embedded_shiny.html) section on rmarkdown website also works perfect in my presentation. But when I replace the path in `system.file` to my app, I get the error:

```
No Shiny application exists at the path ""
```

Here is how I replaced the path:

```
shinyAppDir(
  system.file("dash", package="shiny"),
  options=list(
    width="100%", height=700
  )
)
```

After the error, I tried following:

```
shinyAppDir(
  "C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/Trajectory-one/dash",
  options=list(
    width="100%", height=700
  )
)
```

But then I got a new error:

```
object 'dash' not found
```

Which means that it is not parsing global.R.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please try to check whether you load the appropriate library() or not.please also check you put the file in your working directory.type getwd() to see the working directory and put the file dash there, then run, i think it will work, thanks thanks

Answer (score 5):

I successfully embeded an application within an interactive shiny document with the following rmarkdown  chunk:

````
```
shinyAppDir("D:/Documents/OneDrive/Notes/R-Explore/shiny/01-ages/",
  options=list(
    width="100%", height=550
  )
) 
```
````

All 3 files: the ui.R, server.R, and test.Rmd are at the above absolute path

Answer (score 4):

`system.file("dash", package="shiny")` is definitely not going to work, that's looking for a folder named "dash" inside the shiny package itself, which obviously doesn't exist.

Also we have a limitation in RMarkdown that it doesn't call global.R for embedded Shiny apps, sorry that this fact appears not to have made it into the documentation. https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/211

Finally, unlike in a regular Shiny app, in an RMarkdown document's embedded Shiny apps you can't assume that relative paths from server.R will resolve correctly; that's because many apps can be running in the single session, including the RMarkdown document itself (which is also a Shiny app), so there's no way to make all of them happy.

For now, I recommend you load the data directly in the RMarkdown document and from the sub-apps just assume the data is already loaded--I believe this works, please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

2018 update to this question:

Thanks to the bookdown package, knitr is now able to include HTML widgets, Shiny apps, and arbitrary websites using

```
knitr::included_url()
knitr::include_app()
```

Check out the document in the bookdown book for more examples:
https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/web-pages-and-shiny-apps.html